# Multidex app can't find jar resource but only on some phones

Tags: android, android-multidex

This is sort of an update to an older question I asked, I made it into a new question since I have a lot of new information and I never got any useful answers. I have sort of fixed the issue but I want to understand why.

The old questions:

[java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name javax.servlet.LocalStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227332/java-util-missingresourceexception-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-javax-servle)

Basically, a tiny percentage of my users will experience this crash.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       at MyApp$2.run(MyApp.java:364)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.jar.JarVerifier.removeMetaEntries()' on a null object reference
       at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:381)
       at libcore.net.url.JarURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(JarURLConnectionImpl.java:222)
       at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:444)
       at java.util.ResourceBundle.handleGetBundle(ResourceBundle.java:516)
       at java.util.ResourceBundle.handleGetBundle(ResourceBundle.java:542)
       at java.util.ResourceBundle.handleGetBundle(ResourceBundle.java:542)
       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:228)
       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:139)
       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.(GenericServlet.java)
       at MyApp$2.run(MyApp.java:364)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is happening when my app is trying to instantiate a `Servlet`. Basically `GenericServlet` is trying to load a resource, these are the lines it seems to be crashing on:

```
 private static final String LSTRING_FILE = "javax.servlet.LocalStrings";
 private static ResourceBundle lStrings =
        ResourceBundle.getBundle(LSTRING_FILE);
```

My app creates that `Servlet` as soon as it starts, basically on the `onCreate` of the `Application` class. So the fix for the crash I found, is ugly but it works. If I create the `Servlet` instance inside a thread launched from `onCreate` then it will crash for some users. If I instead create the `Servlet` on `onCreate` without delaying it, then it won't crash.

Basically this won't crash:

```
public void onCreate() {
    .....
    new MyServlet();
    .....
```

But this will:

```
public void onCreate() {
    .....
    new Thread(){..... new Servlet();}
    .....
```

So my guess is that multidex is making sure to keep the `javax` classes and resources on the main dex file when it sees the `Servlet` creation on `onCreate`. But as I mentioned on that previous question, I'm attempting to use `multiDexKeepFile` and more recently I've tried `multiDexKeepProguard`. So why aren't they working?

My latest attempt with `multiDexKeepProguard` in desperation was:

```
-keep class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
-keep class javax.servlet.GenericServlet
-keep class javax.servlet.*
-keep class javax.servlet.LocalStrings
-keepclassmembers class javax.servlet.LocalStrings
```

But it didn't help. The only thing that has helped is moving the first `Servlet` instantiation outside of the `Thread` and into `onCreate`. All subsequent `Servlet` creations and the start of the server happen on a `Thread` without issue.

So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.